# Duplicate content appearing in template under footer when using get_template_part and template_redirect

Tags: php, wordpress, templates

My wp setup is:

- php 7.4
- divi theme and custom child theme

I have made a template in my child theme, when i write a `<p>` the content show properly on the page.
But when i add a function in child's functions.php for pass a variable to my template, the content shows twice on the page: above the footer and below the footer. Maybe using template_redirect is not the correct way to do this?

Function.php:

```
<?php

function theme_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles' );


function form_coav_date() {
    $lucky = 'lucky';
    
    set_query_var( 'lucky', $lucky );
    get_template_part('coav-search', 'lucky');     
}    
add_action('template_redirect', 'form_coav_date');
```

my template coav-search.php:

```
/*
Template Name: coav-search
*/

get_header();

echo '<div style="text-align:center;margin:20px 0;">';
echo '<p>';
echo 'Hello im the custom content, im very ' . $lucky . ' because i have a twin just below the de footer :)';
echo '</p>';
echo '</div>';


get_footer();
```

[the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xu88c.png)

Note that this is outputting a variable for testing, in my real code I have a form in the coav-search.php and process this data in the functions.php, which works except the content is displayed twice.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is that you are trying to include a full template file as a template *part*.

`get_template_part('coav-search', 'lucky')` will copy the whole of `coav-search.php` into the page your are in, but that page will already have a header and footer.

To include the content from `coav-search.php` into your current page, make it a template part instead - this can still be a separate php file, but it isn't a full page because it will be included in other page.

You can create a file called `coav-search-form.php` for example, with this:

```
echo '<div style="text-align:center;margin:20px 0;">';
echo '<p>';
echo 'Hello im the custom content, im very ' . $lucky . ' because i have a twin just below the de footer :)';
echo '</p>';
echo '</div>';
```

Now you can use this in your `template_redirect` *and* in your *coav-search.php* to include the same piece of code in both places.

coav-search.php:

```
/*
Template Name: coav-search
*/
get_header();
get_template_part('coav-search-form', 'lucky');  
get_footer();
```

functions.php

```
function form_coav_date() {
    $lucky = 'lucky';       
    set_query_var( 'lucky', $lucky );
    get_template_part('coav-search-form', 'lucky');     
}    
add_action('template_redirect', 'form_coav_date');
```

Comment: @true-slimen Did this work for you or do you need more help to resolve the question?